# Removing the arrow symbol on icons extracted from shortcuts - VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, shortcut

Ok, so I've finished making this program that allows me to drag and drop files onto a sort of grid so that I can access them anywhere by pressing a hotkey (I set it to f9). However, I don't like the little arrow symbol that accompanies the icon if I add a shortcut. This is how it is currently:

http://prntscr.com/63spzy

As you can see, they all have that blue shortcut arrow and I'd like to get rid of it. I've looked it up on the internet and thought I found a solution and that was to add the "blank.ico" to the folder 
*"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Microsoft \ Windows \ CurrentVersion \ Explorer \ Shell Icons"* and it's worked on all the shortcuts but does not seem to work in my program.

As proof here is a picture of some of the shortcuts in their folders:

http://prntscr.com/63sqay

Thanks in advance of any replies!

Answer (score 0):

already tried to return the application's full path associated with the shortcut and extract the icon?

- Return full path when lnk file is dragged and dropped.
- Extract icon from original file.